# Why do I get this error when I call an activity from an other?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a main activity and I call a second "demo from android studio" activity when I click on a button of the first activity like this :

```
public void createNetworkButtonClicked (View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, WiFiDirectActivity.class); // that works
   startActivity(intent); // that does not work
}
```

I get this error :

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3698)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17337)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you match the name **createNetworkButtonClicked** as defined in xml?

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/createNetworkButton"
        android:id="@+id/createNetworkButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="createNetworkButtonClicked"/>

Comment: I modifier the xml but I get a new error.

Comment: What's the new error? Are you using this in a Fragment?

Comment: No is it easy to use ? I am just using two normal activities

Comment: No, its not possible to use xml onClick callback in Fragment. Can you paste some more code including WiFiDirectActivity. Have you also declared that new activity in manifest?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the declaration of the activity was bad.

Answer (score 0):

There can be possibly two reasons for it.

1) Check your method name in onClick attribute of XML file. It should match with the name of the method in java.

2) Create an activity instead of creating individual XML file and Java file for the second class. You can create Activity by right clicking on app folder-->new-->activity-->empty activity.